# window.onload inside of Astro js not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, astrojs

I have a set of Astro components to be called by my App:

```
apps/myProject

libs/components/header
```

Inside the header.astro component, I have a script that I want to be run once the entire page is rendered:

```
<script is:inline>
  console.log('hej!');
  window.onload = (e) => {
    console.log('loaded!');
  };
</script>
```

The `'hej!'` is being printed but not the `'loaded!'`. Why is that?

For me, it is not clear how the component's lifecycle works in Astro, and I have followed [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71495318/how-to-use-document-and-window-element-in-astro-js) by adding the `is:inline` property to the script tag, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

The solution shall be as simple as

```html
<script is:inline>
    console.log('hej!');
    console.log('loaded!');
</script>
```

which yields

[image]

## Misunderstandings and Misleading solutions

### question solution proposal

this script inside a `page.astro` works, in case the question pretend that it does not, it is very important to provide more elements like a complete example project as the error is most likely somewhere else not in the provided code.

```html
<script is:inline>
  console.log('hej!');
  window.onload = (e) => {
    console.log('loaded!');
  };
</script>
```

I took it in a default astro example and it yields the following output

[image]

but is not ideal because window.onload is not needed : see [When to use "window.onload"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180251/when-to-use-window-onload)

see astro official examples to take as test basis here (https://github.com/withastro/astro/tree/main/examples)

### adding frontmatter separation

The solution below unnecessarily adds `--- ---` which is an optional frontmatter entry, when not available then the content is interpreted as the second body part which is where the script is supposed to be located

```html
---
---

<script>
    console.log('hello');
    window.onload = (e) => {
        console.log('loaded!');
    };
</script>
```

### adding type module or hoist

please udpate and see https://docs.astro.build/en/migrate/#new-default-script-behavior

from there you get to know that :

- **BREAKING**: `<script hoist>` is the new default `<script>` behavior. The `hoist` attribute has been removed. To use the new default behaviour, make sure there are no other attributes on the `<script>` tag. For example, remove `type="module"` if you were using it before.

### using is:inline

The question author has been mislead by another post ([How to use document and window element in astro JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71495318/how-to-use-document-and-window-element-in-astro-js)), taken as granted which is wrong and I submitted an answer to correct it because `is:inline` inside `<script>` is not needed and has unintended side effects like unnecessarily duplicating the script code, see a direct link to this answer there [How to use document and window element in astro JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71495318/how-to-use-document-and-window-element-in-astro-js#74839926)

Answer (score 0):

Think of `*.astro` files as all server side, you cannot use
`<script>...</script>` inside the

```
---
---
```

but you can use `<script></script>` in the html part of astro file. the below example works fine for me.

```
---
---

<script>
    console.log('hello');
    window.onload = (e) => {
        console.log('loaded!');
    };
</script>

<p>hello world!</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use load modules on the client with `hoist`.

```
<script type="module" hoist>
  console.log('loaded!');
</script>
```

`window.onload` isn't necessary since ES modules are automatically deferred.

Comment: what about `window.location.href` ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: How to use it? Location is always undefined and inside a script you cannot share it with the template

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Can you please open a new question? You can ping me or link it here if you want me to take a look.